# Template function to load big endian from byte array

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to implement template function, for reading from byte array in big endian order. This is my current implementation:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T load_big_endian(const unsigned char* buf) {
  T res {};

  std::size_t size = sizeof(T) - 1;

  for (int i = 0; i <= size; i += 1) {
    res |= static_cast<T>(buf[size - i] << (i * 8));
  }

  return res;
}
```

Is this a good solution? Or better use a separate functions for each type, like `load32_big_endian`? And what problems can I face using this approach?

Comment: This loads a single object of type T?

Comment: On C++17 and later, you should be using `std::byte`. On C++20, you have `std::bit_cast`. Why are you not using these?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili yes, for example `load_big_endian<uint32_t>(buf)`

Comment: @CodyGray because buffer comes from `ifstream.read(...)`, but i will look into `std::bit_cast`

Comment: Why would that matter? What you're doing here is strictly unsafe in the hands of an optimizing compiler. Also, if you're intending to limit `T` to integral types that support bitwise-OR, you should be adding some SFINAE or `static_assert` magic here, too.

Comment: @CodyGray thx for the advice

Comment: @CodyGray can you please explain which part is unsafe? using `unsigned char*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
[[nodiscard]] T load_big_endian(std::byte const* const buf) noexcept 
  requires std::is_trivial_v<T> 
{
  T res;
  std::reverse_copy(buf, buf + sizeof res, reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(&res));
  return res;
}
```

Highlights:

- `std::byte` conveys the intention more explicitly. You can still use `unsigned char` if that's a requirement, either will work.
- `reverse_copy` is easier to use.
- making sure that the type is trivial is a good idea to make sure we don't cause UB. You can loosen this restriction if needed.

Comment: Since this is C++20, a concept would be more idiomatic than an assertion there :)

Comment: @CássioRenan you're right. It's hard to break old habits :)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili But isn't it casts away const and causing UB?
`Only the following conversions can be done with reinterpret_cast, except when such conversions would cast away constness or volatility.` - from cpp reference

Comment: @xxx where am I casting away const? Casting away const would require a `const_cast` which I am not using, therefore I am not casting away const.